# How enter a lot of data without pulling down cell?

Tags: excel, libreoffice

I have to enter a lot of same data, and i don't wanna pulling down cell to autoenter it.

For example:

```
abc
```

```
abc \/ 10000 times
```

To do it i use mouse, but it's not fine. How to make it without using mouse pulling down cell?

Comment: [**Ctrl+D**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/02140100.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=.uno:FillDown#bm_id3145173)?

Comment: See [**here**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/305134/calc-how-to-drag-cell-content-until-very-last-row/?answer=305142#post-id-305142)

Comment: That's it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to fill cells with a copy of the first. Beside a simple Copy-n-paste, here is a detailed recipe with more flexibility.

In your example:

1. Enter "abc" into the first cell, let's say "A1".
2. Mark the range you want to fill. Go to cell "A10000" and type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>. The cursor is now at "A1" and the range downto "A10000" is marked.
3. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, and all the cells are filled with "abc".

Notes:

- This works also with formulas. Relative references are maintained, absolute references keep their "coordinates".
- In the menu "Sheet"-"Fill cells..." are more commands for the other directions.
- If you already have a filled range, you can simplify your navigation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Up/Down/Left/Right</kbd>, because these jump to the end of the range. For example, if you like to fill the second column with the formula "=UPPER(A1)", do it like this:

  1. Go to cell "B1" and enter "=UPPER(A1)" in any way you see fit.
  2. Go to cell "A1".
  3. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>, and the cursor is now at cell "A10000".
  4. Type <kbd>Right</kbd>, and the cursor is now at cell "B10000".
  5. Type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>, and the cursor is at cell "B1" with the range downto "B10000" marked.
  6. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, and all cells "B1" to "B10000" are filled with the formulas "=UPPER(A1)" to "=UPPER(A10000)".

  - Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> marks the cells as you move the cursor by keys.
  - Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> "empowers" the cursor keys to move to the end of the current filled range.